# Redux and React Native - how can I connect a callback to dispatch

Tags: react-native, redux

I want to create a tag cloud that lets people toggle tags on or off as filters to a search.  I'm presenting this as a tab on my results page (I'm using flux routing, if that's relevant).

I'm using a custom component called ToggleButton that flips between an enabled/disabled state by changing colour.

In my container I'm passing a callback function as a prop to the button, like this:

```
onStateChangeCallback = (newState, buttonId) => {
    console.log("container " + newState + " " + buttonId);
}

render = () => {                
    const { Layout, tags } = this.props;        
    return (
      <Layout
        tags={tags}
        onStateChange={this.onStateChangeCallback}            
      />
    );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    toggleTag,    
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({    
    tags: state.tagfilterreducer.tags || [],
});
```

The Layout component looks like this:

```
const RecipeTagFilterComponent = ({tags, onStateChange}) => {

  return (
    <Container>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={2}
        data={tags}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ToggleButton textValue={item.name} onStateChange={onStateChange} buttonId={item.id} />
        )}
      />
    </Container>
  );

}
```

The ToggleButton class looks like this:

```
export default class ToggleButton extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)        
    }

    state = {    
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <SimpleToggleButton textValue={this.props.textValue} onStateChange={this.props.onStateChange} buttonId={this.props.buttonId} />
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

Lastly the SimpleToggleButton looks like this:

```
class SimpleToggleButton extends Component {

    state = {
        toggle: false,
    }

    _onPress() {
        const newState = !this.state.toggle;
        this.setState({toggle:newState});
        this.props.onStateChange && this.props.onStateChange(newState, this.props.buttonId);
    }


    render() {
        const {toggle} = this.state;
        const buttonTextColor = toggle ? "white" : "black";
        const buttonBackground = toggle ? "dodgerblue" : "#BDBDBD";

        return (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this._onPress()}
                    style={{margin:10, flex: 1, height: 60, backgroundColor: buttonBackground, justifyContent:'center', borderRadius: 30}}
                    >

                    <Text style={{color:buttonTextColor , backgroundColor: 'transparent', textAlign: 'center', fontSize:16}}>{this.props.textValue}</Text>


                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

My callback is executed properly when I press the button.

How can I amend my `mapDispatchToProps` so that pressing the button will dispatch an action called `TOGGLE_FILTER_TAG`?

===========EDIT - SOLUTION============

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class FilterListingContainer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        Layout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,        
        tags: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape()).isRequired,        
    }

    render = () => {                
        const { Layout, tags } = this.props;        
        return (
          <Layout
            tags={tags}
            onStateChange={this.props.clickHandler} // clickHandler prop is defined in mapDispatchToProps
          />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({    
    tags: state.tagfilterreducer.tags || [],
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        clickHandler: (newState, buttonId) => {                      
            dispatch({
                type: 'TOGGLE_FILTER_TAG',
                data: buttonId,
            })        
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FilterListingContainer);
```

Comment: where is your current mapDispatchToProps that you want to amend?

Comment: I've edited it to include it.  Your solution looks like it's going to work, I'm already using react-redux and your solution looks a lot like what I'm trying to do.  Going to try now and accept.

Comment: Please edit your question to include final pastebin solution link that worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you first need to intall redux binding package for react called [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux)
then you can do something like

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { TOGGLE_FILTER_TAG } from 'youractions'

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    clickHandler: () => {
      dispatch(TOGGLE_FILTER_TAG())
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(yourcomponent)
```

`clickHandler` will then be available inside `yourcomponent`

Comment: How will I pass the buttonId to my reducer?  Should I pass `clickHandler` in place of my current `onStateChangeCallback`

Comment: You can pass arguments to clickHandler, and can modify dispatch call to use arguments during dispatch

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I can't get the mapping to trigger.  My code is at https://pastebin.com/yu80M7JN ... Please could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Andy there is no need to define `clickHandler` inside `FilterListingContainer` since container is already connected and will get `clickHandler` from `mapDispatchToProps`. Pass `onStateChange={this.props.clickHandler}` to your `Layout` component

Comment: Thanks again!  I'll edit the pastebin with the final product to keep this solution alive